# Silent Printing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, printing, office-automation

**I want to print a DOCX document silently (without print dialog) in javascript**. I actualy have a path of document but i want to print specific pages. Lets say client want to print first page. Is there any way of printing a specific page without print dialog? I can also consider hardcoding a page number programmatically. So that everytime first page will be printed. Help required.

Thanks

Comment: Only if the browser support it, I hope not because on many web sites, my printer can potential print advertise pages with out my permission.

Comment: If you are using IE, have a look at ActiveX

Comment: @pax162 basically my web application is only designed for IE, i am currently using Edraw Office OCX but it prints all the pages with print dialog. They have mentioned in their documentation that print dialog can be hidden programmatically and specific pages can be printed. but i have tried and came up with no success. That is why i was considering writing my own javascript. Because i am unable to find any real help, well thanks alot for your reply.